# Elastic scaterring of neutrinos - Why does the electron neutrino dominate this channel

Tags: scattering, neutrinos

Could anyone add more detail to this statement [off wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudbury_Neutrino_Observatory#Electron_elastic_scattering)

> In the elastic scattering interaction, a neutrino collides with an
>   atomic electron and imparts some of its energy to the electron. All
>   three neutrinos can participate in this interaction through the
>   exchange of the neutral Z boson, and electron neutrinos can also
>   participate with the exchange of a charged W boson. For this reason
>   this interaction is dominated by electron neutrinos, and this is the
>   channel through which the Super-Kamiokande (Super-K) detector can
>   observe solar neutrinos.

1) Why does the $\nu_{e}$ having the $W^{±}$ channel in addition to the $Z$ channel cause the $\nu_{e}$ to dominate this interaction?

2) At what point is a photon emitted so that Super-K can detect this interaction?

Comment: In response to 2): Super-K is a water Cherenkov detector. The light is generated by the recoiled electron causing Cherenkov radiation in the water surrounding the photomultiplier tubes.

Comment: Would the electron be moving fast enough for Cherenkov radiation?

Comment: The speed of the electron needs to be about 3/4 of c for that to happen. That means a kinetic energy of about 270 keV = 0.27 MeV. Solar neutrinos have energies of  about 1 to 10 MeV. In general there is more than sufficient energy.

Comment: handwaving: extra Feynman diagrams means extra probability of interaction https://www.kvi.nl/~loehner/saf_seminar/2010/neutrino-electron-interactions.pdf figs 5.1.3a

Comment: Doesn't page 4 mean that $\nu_{\mu}$ and $\nu_{\tau}$ can interact via the Z boson channel? or (a guess) is it a higher threshold energy so for specifically solar neutrinos it just can't happen?